# Cron stops after some time of execution

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

I have a cron  in server, and it set as 2 6 *** wget http://test.com/test.php

In this file, it fetch 10000 records  and manipulate.
While i executing this file, it stops  after some time of execution(may be, it reached maximum execution time.There is no application error as it works for small amount of records).

I have  a solution like, fetch first  100 records then process,close mysql connection,then sleep for 2 minutes, then take next 100 records.

Will it  fix the execution time issue or both are same in effect ?

Comment: @Dagon,No, its in my client server

Answer (score 0):

if you sleep for two minutes, the script will reach the default max. execution time of 30 seconds within the first sleep cycle.

you can either increase that limit with

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 300); //for 5 minutes
```

which, however, is just a symptomic fix, not a real solution, or change your algorithm so that your records are chunked in several sets, which then can be processed sequentially by several cronjobs running one after another or parallely by several cronjobs at the same time, [php pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) or [forking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) - if those two options are available with your server configuration.

You should definitely check the outputs of your cronjob manually, however, to find possible problems other than the execution time, for example memory leaks.